# Rails where method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to get this working, I have got this

> syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' @tm = Master.where("merchant_deep_link" = ne)

And this is in my controller

```
@newevent = Event.find(params[:id])
ne = @newevent.Master
@tm = Master.where("merchant_deep_link" = ne)
```

How do i go about making the `@tm` show all of the results that have the `ne` inside the `Merchant_deep_link` and return the row (there is probably only one of these however it does have to scan 24k rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i go about making the `@tm` show all of the results that have the ne inside the `Merchant_deep_link`

```
@newevent = Event.find params[:id]
@tm = Master.where merchant_deep_link: @newevent.master.id
```

This will return a `collection` object to `@tm`, which means you have to loop through the records - probably with [`.each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each)...

```
@tm.each do |tm|
  tm.id
end
```

--

> if i run tm.id it doesnt show the id

If you want to return the `id` for `@tm`, you'll be able to use [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck):

```
@newevent = Event.find params[:id]
@tm = Master.where(merchant_deep_link: @newevent.master.id).pluck(:id)
```

This will *still* return a `collection`, but most importantly, that collection will consist of `id`s only.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
@tm = Master.where('merchant_deep_link' => ne.id)
```

Or

```
@tm = Master.where(merchant_deep_link: ne.id)
```

And, by the way, `ne = @newevent.Master` should probably be `ne = @newevent.master` or something *similar*.

Comment: Hey, This kinda works, However if i run tm.id it doesnt show the id?

Comment: @SamAdmit: it is a collection (i.e. array of objects), so you should either iterate through it, or  just fetch the one you want, for example, first, using `first` (or use `find_by` instead of `where`)

Comment: Still getthing nothing back, i've tried find_by instead and it said nil (even thogh it works fine)